# Problem with installation in Ubuntu 12.10 Quantal

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!
I'm trying to install ros-fuerte-desktop-full in my Ubuntu 12.10.
If I add to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list:

```
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu quantal main
```

I get:

```
Impossible to find ros-fuerte-desktop-full
```

Instead, if I add to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list (like in the installation guide):

```
 deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu precise main
```

I get:

```
    I seguenti pacchetti hanno dipendenze non soddisfatte:
 ros-fuerte-desktop-full : Dipende: ros-fuerte-nodelet-core (= 1.6.5-s1347135186~precise) ma non sta per essere installato
                           Dipende: ros-fuerte-geometry-tutorials (= 0.1.3-s1348604699~precise) ma non sta per essere installato
                           Dipende: ros-fuerte-orocos-kinematics-dynamics (= 0.2.3-s1347124598~precise) ma non sta per essere installato
                           Dipende: ros-fuerte-filters (= 1.6.0-s1347135144~precise) ma non sta per essere installato
                           Dipende: ros-fuerte-slam-gmapping (= 1.2.7-s1347173499~precise) ma non sta per essere installato
                           Dipende: ros-fuerte-simulator-gazebo (= 1.6.16-s1347170734~precise) ma non sta per essere installato
                           Dipende: ros-fuerte-visualization (= 1.8.14-s1348597795~precise) ma non sta per essere installato
                           Dipende: ros-fuerte-vision-opencv (= 1.8.8-s1349901192~precise) ma non sta per essere installato
                           Dipende: ros-fuerte-perception-pcl (= 1.2.3-s1347169792~precise) ma non sta per essere installato
                           Dipende: ros-fuerte-geometry-experimental (= 0.2.3-s1347135545~precise) ma non sta per essere installato
                           Dipende: ros-fuerte-robot-model-visualization (= 0.1.2-s1347130327~precise) ma non sta per essere installato
                           Dipende: ros-fuerte-common-tutorials (= 0.2.3-s1348604586~precise) ma non sta per essere installato
                           Dipende: ros-fuerte-image-pipeline (= 1.8.5-s1349904529~precise) ma non sta per essere installato
                           Dipende: ros-fuerte-bfl (= 0.1.0-s1347124594~precise) ma non sta per essere installato
                           Dipende: ros-fuerte-diagnostics-monitors (= 1.4.3-s1347134955~precise) ma non sta per essere installato
                           Dipende: ros-fuerte-common-rosdeps (= 1.2.0-s1347123654~precise) ma non sta per essere installato
                           Dipende: ros-fuerte-geometry-visualization (= 0.1.1-s1347141529~precise) ma non sta per essere installato
                           Dipende: ros-fuerte-image-common (= 1.8.0-s1347135209~precise) ma non sta per essere installato
                           Dipende: ros-fuerte-bond-core (= 1.6.3-s1347130095~precise) ma non sta per essere installato
                           Dipende: ros-fuerte-python-qt-binding (= 0.1.9-s1348595568~precise) ma non sta per essere installato
                           Dipende: ros-fuerte-visualization-common (= 1.8.4-s1347130647~precise) ma non sta per essere installato
                           Dipende: ros-fuerte-physics-ode (= 1.8.0-s1347123681~precise) ma non sta per essere installato
                           Dipende: ros-fuerte-driver-common (= 1.4.0-s1347139831~precise) ma non sta per essere installato
                           Dipende: ros-fuerte-executive-smach (= 1.2.0-s1347135552~precise) ma non sta per essere installato
                           Dipende: ros-fuerte-stage (= 1.6.6-s1347135364~precise) ma non sta per essere installato
                           Dipende: ros-fuerte-dynamic-reconfigure (= 1.4.2-s1347130094~precise) ma non sta per essere installato
                           Dipende: ros-fuerte-image-transport-plugins (= 1.8.2-s1349904795~precise) ma non sta per essere installato
                           Dipende: ros-fuerte-xacro (= 1.6.1-s1347130592~precise) ma non sta per essere installato
                           Dipende: ros-fuerte-robot-model (= 1.8.1-s1347135356~precise) ma non sta per essere installato
                           Dipende: ros-fuerte-bullet (= 2.79-s1347124531~precise) ma non sta per essere installato
                           Dipende: ros-fuerte-pluginlib (= 1.8.0-s1347130240~precise) ma non sta per essere installato
                           Dipende: ros-fuerte-geometry (= 1.8.2-s1347130162~precise) ma non sta per essere installato
                           Dipende: ros-fuerte-visualization-tutorials (= 0.6.3-s1348599593~precise) ma non sta per essere installato
                           Dipende: ros-fuerte-executive-smach-visualization (= 1.0.2-s1347140656~precise) ma non sta per essere installato
                           Dipende: ros-fuerte-laser-pipeline (= 1.4.4-s1347170493~precise) ma non sta per essere installato
                           Dipende: ros-fuerte-robot-model-tutorials (= 0.1.2-s1347123686~precise) ma non sta per essere installato
                           Dipende: ros-fuerte-common (= 1.8.0-s1347135482~precise) ma non sta per essere installato
                           Dipende: ros-fuerte-diagnostics (= 1.6.4-s1347135107~precise) ma non sta per essere installato
                           Dipende: ros-fuerte-navigation (= 1.8.3-s1347171894~precise) ma non sta per essere installato
E: Impossibile correggere i problemi, ci sono pacchetti danneggiati bloccati.
```

The output is in italian and it means that there are dependancies not satisfied.

Any help? Thank you very much and sorry for may bad english.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46553/problem-with-installation-in-ubuntu-12.10-quantal/) by [Usbetti](https://answers.ros.org/users/3442/usbetti/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-10-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [niosus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2034/niosus/) on 2012-10-22**:
Not sure about that, but I remember first updating my Ubuntu to 12.04 from 11.10. Usually ROS doesn't catch up so fast with the versions of ubuntu. I would suggest updating a couple of month after the release of the new version.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-22**:
@nios is right. There is no ros for 12.10 yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no ros for  Ubuntu 12.10. As far as I have read, there might be support for ubuntu 12.10 when ROS Groovy is out. The scheduled data is 15 Nov, if I am not wrong.

See

http://answers.ros.org/question/46446/ros-packpages-scheduled-date-for-ubuntu-1210-quantal/

and

http://answers.ros.org/question/44823/ros-and-ubuntu-1210-quantal-working/

for more details if you can not wait for the official release.

---

Originally posted by [Victor_ocv2](https://answers.ros.org/users/3431/victor_ocv2/) with karma: 483 on 2012-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-01-14**:
Groovy had been released with support for Quantal.